Kohonen neural network for determining the quadrant of a point plane
I need to implement a Kohonen neural network (without teacher) to determine the quadrant of the plane (from 1 to 8) of a point. A vector of coordinates [x, y, z] is fed to the input of the neural network. At the output, we get a vector by which we determine which quadrant the point belongs to.
Here is my code for training a neural network:
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def generate_dataset(
        size: int,
        high: float = 10.0
) -> list[tuple[npt.NDArray[npt.NDArray[float]], npt.NDArray[npt.NDArray[float]]]]:
    dataset = []

    quadrants_multipliers = {
        1: (1, 1, 1),
        2: (-1, 1, 1),
        3: (-1, -1, 1),
        4: (1, -1, 1),
        5: (1, 1, -1),
        6: (-1, 1, -1),
        7: (-1, -1, -1),
        8: (1, -1, -1)
    }

    for quadrant in range(1, 8 + 1):
        dataset += [
            (
                np.array([[x, y, z]]) * quadrants_multipliers[quadrant],
                np.eye(8)[quadrant - 1].reshape(1, 8)
            ) for x, y, z in zip(
                np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=high, size=size),
                np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=high, size=size),
                np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=high, size=size)
            )
        ]

    return dataset

def train(
        dataset: list[tuple[npt.NDArray[npt.NDArray[float]], npt.NDArray[npt.NDArray[float]]]],
        learning_rate: float,
        epochs: int
) -> npt.NDArray[npt.NDArray[float]]:

    W = np.random.randn(3, 8)

    for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):
        random_indexes = np.random.choice(len(dataset), size=len(dataset), replace=False)
        for index in random_indexes:
            x = dataset[index][0]  # [[x, y, z]]
            y = dataset[index][1]

            x_normalized = x / np.sqrt(np.sum(x ** 2))

            z = np.dot(x_normalized, W)

            W[0][z.argmax()] += learning_rate * (x[0][0] - W[0][z.argmax()])
            W[1][z.argmax()] += learning_rate * (x[0][1] - W[1][z.argmax()])
            W[2][z.argmax()] += learning_rate * (x[0][2] - W[2][z.argmax()])

        learning_rate = learning_rate / epoch

    return W

def calc_accuracy(
        dataset: list[tuple[npt.NDArray[npt.NDArray[float]], npt.NDArray[npt.NDArray[float]]]],
        W: npt.NDArray[npt.NDArray[float]]) -> float:
    correct = 0
    for x, y in dataset:
        z = np.dot(x, W)
        if z.argmax() == y.argmax():
            correct += 1
    return (correct / len(dataset)) * 100


def draw_accuracy_epoch_plots(
        datasets: list[list[tuple[npt.NDArray[npt.NDArray[float]], npt.NDArray[npt.NDArray[float]]]]],
        epoch_number: int
) -> None:
    for index, dataset in enumerate(datasets):
        accuracy_list = []
        accuracy_list_2 = []
        for epochs in range(1, epoch_number + 1):
            W = train(dataset, learning_rate=0.7, epochs=epochs)
            accuracy_list.append(calc_accuracy(dataset, W))
            accuracy_list_2.append(calc_accuracy(generate_dataset(15), W))

        plt.subplot(3, 2, (2 * index) + 1)
        plt.plot(accuracy_list)

        plt.subplot(3, 2, (2 * index) + 2)
        plt.plot(accuracy_list_2)


def main() -> None:
    draw_accuracy_epoch_plots([generate_dataset(250), generate_dataset(500), generate_dataset(1000)], 200)

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


In the code, I calculate the accuracy of neural network predictions for different epochs. As a result, I get an accuracy from 0 to 45%, which does not suit me. At the same time, the neural network very often produces 0% matches.
How can I fix this if changing the learning rate and epochs doesn't help? Can I add layers (I haven't found the answer to this question)? Or maybe I built the learning algorithm incorrectly?
Note:
I have accuracy charts that I've created yesterday - it took about half an hour, maybe more. The accuracy can be seen on the Y axis, and the epoch on the X axis. On the left are graphs for different training selections (the number of points in such a sample is signed above the graph), and on the graphs on the right we use the weight obtained from the sample from the graph on the left for a new test sample of 200 points. And it seems to me that this should not be the case, the schedule should essentially grow, but it is not.


Yes, sorry for some confusion of concepts. "Without a teacher" - I meant that the standard Kohonen network learning scheme is used, that is, we use only the input data vector, but do not use the correct output data vector, as for other algorithms.
In order for you to see the whole code, I am editing the main block of code in the question.

Let's first fix this:             zmax = z.argmax()             W[0][zmax] += learning_rate * (x[0][0] - W[0][zmax])             W[1][zmax] += learning_rate * (x[0][1] - W[1][zmax])             W[2][zmax] += learning_rate * (x[0][2] - W[2][zmax]). No need to call, six times. Do you have CPU powers? cuz I don't. How long does it take to run the code?

This will not fully fix. But how about we change W = np.random.randn(3, 8) to W = np.random.rand(3, 32)

Can you plot the convergence of your training per epoch? Something like the plots in here? It'd be easier to see things and find out, if there is any convergence at all. I'd increase the number of epochs, but that also requires CPU.

Also post a question in here and ask about convergence. Then, post a question in here and ask about improving the performance.

Create all your datasets first. Make them global. You don't have to pass them into every function call. Can we use caching to hit the cache, if things are already calced?

If I replace W = np.random.rand(3, 8) to W = np.random.rand(3, 32). Then won't I have 32 neural network outputs? Since my weights were calculated for 8 outputs, that is, for 8 squares, and this was just achieved (3, 8)? And i tried to do (3, 32) - it didn't change anything, the accuracy became even lower.

Yes, charting takes quite a long time, I made some corrections, including those that you suggested, it really accelerated the speed of the program. However, this did not affect the accuracy of the neural network itself in any way.

I have charts that I created yesterday - it took about half an hour, maybe more. The accuracy can be seen on the Y axis, and the epoch on the X axis. On the left are graphs for different training selections (the number of points in such a sample is signed above the graph), and on the graphs on the right we use the weight obtained from the sample from the graph on the left for a new test sample of 200 points. And it seems to me that this should not be the case, the schedule should essentially grow, but it is not. I dont know how to post a photo in a comment, but here https://postimg.cc/7Cd87SQd

We are "initializing" and continue updating weights, every time we run the algorithms. Is this right? If yes, that'd be a problem. How is this would even converge? We also have a new set of datasets for every run. Right?

The exact same algorithm for rendering the accuracy dependence on the epoch works in my other program, which uses a neural network that uses back error propagation, the only difference is how the weights are updated.

@Slyne you don't post images in comments. In fact, you shouldn't as much engage in comments as you should [edit] your question to improve it. In this case, a community member did it for you. Comments are to ask for clarifications, each question should stand on its own.
